# Weak measurement and weak value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurement-problem

The concept of weak measurements (and weak values)  have become popular in Quantum information community, as I can see quite a few papers in arXiv. Since I am from Mathematical background (and the writing styles are different in these disciplines), can someone explain just the mathematical concept behind it, in terms of say a proper algorithm, and /or POVM/ Kraus operator language; or if there is already some paper/ survey paper written in the spirit mentioned above. Advanced thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: There is at least a strong controversy on the subject of weak measurements on the physical side (for the "opposition" point of view you can see e.g. this [post](https://qbnets.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/dull-measurements-aka-weak-measurements/)). I suspect also that, due to the controversial nature of the "theory" (and almost triviality of the related mathematics), there has been no big effort to translate these ideas in rigorous terms...but this is just my feeling ;-)

Comment: After a quick reading, I think that this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0295v3.pdf) (cited in the linked discussions) is quite clarifying both mathematically and physically (and so now I am also convinced that these weak measurements are uninteresting, and ambiguously used :-D).

Comment: @yuggib thanks for your comment. exactly for the same controversial nature, i would like to know a rigorous mathematical definition. (may be i am wrong, but the word rigour has different meanings among maths and physics community). yet, with all the troubles/conjectures/paradoxes(!) several papers keep on appearing in arxiv (and somehow published in reputed journals). that is frustrating for me. i want to see how to start from a mathematical point of view and come to a conclusion by myself. thanking you once again, --

Comment: I agree that what we (mathematicians) call rigour is different from what the physicists mean. Anyways, the  Parrott paper seems reasonably rigorous (it makes examples in finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, and acknowledges in the end that in infinite dimensional ones some of the assumptions (others make) are unjustified and probably wrong); in addition it clarifies, in my opinion, the ideas behind these weak measurements so it can be a good starting point. However I perfectly understand your desire to come to your own conclusions ;-)

Comment: RSG : you should look at weak measurement from the experimentalist viewpoint as well as examining the mathematical concept. See [this](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/dec/16/physics-world-reveals-its-top-10-breakthroughs-for-2011) physicsworld article and check out [Jeff Lundeen](http://www.photonicquantum.info/). As for the physics concept, weak measurement is like plotting out a seismic wave using little sticks, whilst ordinary measurement is like absorbing the whole seismic wave with a stick the size of a mountain range.

Comment: Thanks @JohnDuffield. I really like your analogy:) If I understand correctly, you are telling me to consider the experimental limitations as well. this is something, I am ignorant about (being a math student). Let me check the links you have given, and I wish I can understand at least $\epsilon$ of the experiments :) Thanking you once again ---

Comment: Mt pleasure RSG. See Jeff Lundeen's [semi-technical explanation](http://www.photonicquantum.info/Research/SemiTechnical_Wavefunction.html): _"We have developed a methodology for measuring the wavefunction directly, by repeating many weak measurements on a group of systems that have been prepared with identical wavefunctions. By repeating the measurements, the knowledge of the wavefunction accumulates to the point where high precision can be restored..."_